# Sefarim about how to respond or debate an apikores?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, jewish-books

A friend of mine told me either the Steipler (or another gadol, my friend was not certain but recalled) wrote a Sefer concerning responding to an apikores. My main question inquires if any Sefer contains information of the sort, either dialectical like the Kuzari or simply expository. My secondary question  asks if the Steipler had actually written a Sefer of the sort.

I’m aware the term Apikores is variably defined so I suppose any definition brought forth by a Talmudic authority is sufficient.

Comment: “...if any Sefer contains information of the sort” - an aptly named *sefer* by Haym Bloch ‘[Ve’da ma she’tashiv](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/21733)’ contains responses [to the Vatican] on various attacks on Jewish texts. Aryeh Kaplan’s pamphlet of answers to missionaries was reprinted in the Aryeh Kaplan Anthology (I forget which volume).

Comment: The only effective answer for an apiqoreis is living the Torah as it is supposed to be lived, and letting him in on the experience. It's experience that leads people to consider some given "self evident" or "quetionable", or to decide a question is "an interesting puzzle that I'm sure has an answer" or "a clear disproof of the entire thesis". Nothing about reason -- the postulates or the reasons we use to build theorems from them -- is really so clearly true or false that you can prove things. To quote the Kuzari, 1:13...

Comment: (יג) אָמַר הֶחָבֵר: זֶה שֶׁאַתָּה אוֹמֵר הִיא הַדָּת הַהֶקֵּשִׁית הַמִּנְהָגִית, מֵבִיא אֵלֶיהָ הָעִיּוּן, וְנִכְנָסִים בָּהּ סְפֵקוֹת רַבּוֹת. וְאִם תִּשְׁאַל הַפִּילוֹסוֹפִים עָלֶיהָ אֵינְךָ מוֹצֵא אוֹתָם מַסְכִּימִים עַל מַעֲשֶׂה אֶחָד וְלֹא עַל דַּעַת אֶחָת, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהֵם טְעָנוֹת, יֵשׁ מֵהֶם מַה שֶּׁהֵם יְכוֹלִים לְהַעֲמִיד מוֹפֵת, וּמֵהֶם מַה שֶּׁיַּסְפִּיקוּ בָם, וּמֵהֶם מַה שֶּׁלֹּא יַסְפִּיקוּ בָם, כָּל שֶׁכֵּן שֶׁיַעֲמִידוּ בָם מוֹפֵת.